# Apache Kafka 0.8.2.1 - Producer (Java API) does not write messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I set up Apache Kafka 0.8.2.1 in a CentOS environment, created a topic and sent / received some dummy messages via the command line producer / consumer.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot that worked well. No I'm writing a custom producer to get my messages from Java to the topic.

```
package de.jofre.kafka;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

public class TestProducer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "192.168.145.130:9092");
        props.put("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
        props.put("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());

        KafkaProducer<String, String> prod = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);

        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<String, String>("test", "Kafka is great");
        prod.send(record);

        prod.close();
    }
}
```

Calling the shown main does not result into a message on the Kafka topic nor does it print any error message.

Does anybody have an idea why the message does not arrive in my topic?

Comment: could you please try removing `props.put("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());`

Comment: Changing only the bootstrap.servers property and the topic to write to, your code runs perfectly on my machine. Is there any more information you can lend as to what is happening? Because the problem doesn't seem to be coming your code, assuming your ipaddress and topic name is correct.

Comment: @user2720864: When I remove the property I get a ConfigException telling me that the key.serializer property is required.

Comment: @morganw09dev: Thanks for testing. Do you use Version 0.8.2.1? What version of the kafka java libs do you use? I tried the code in our test environment as well as in a local VM. None of them works.

Comment: Yes, I tested on Version 0.8.2.1 and 0.8.2.0. The only dependency I have in my pom.xml is 
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>0.8.2.1</version>
With some exclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to morganw09dev I found the answer. I tested with the dependencies *org.apache.kafka kafka_2.11 0.8.2.1* and *org.apache.kafka kafka-clients 0.8.2.1*. Non of them worked.

The dependency that actually worked is *org.apache.kafka kafka_2.10 0.8.2.1*. I consider this to be a bug since I downloaded and run the kafka_2.11 binaries.